# Sprite orbiting on a point

Tags: ios, spritekit

I was wondering how to make a Sprite do an orbit on a determinated point in SpriteKit. I tried to set the `anchorPoint` of the Sprite orbiting with the center point but it doesn't work. Please can someone help me?

Comment: When you say "orbit" do you mean travel a circular path around the centre point or do you mean follow a path around a centre point that is more controlled by things like gravity, mass, velocity etc. i.e. using celestial mechanics…

Answer (score 1):

Use the parenting to your advantage.  From the [SKNode Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/index.html):

> When a node’s coordinate system is scaled or rotated, this transformation is applied both to the node’s own content and to that of its descendants.

First, create an `SKNode` (your center node) and set its position to the center of the orbit. Next, add the `SKSpriteNode` that should be orbiting as child to the center node. Set the child node's position to the radius of the orbit ((0, 50) for a radius of 50).

When you rotate the center node, the child will "orbit" around it.